# The .py File Type changed. I want it back

Tags: python

I have a Python 2.7 on a Windows 7. The Type of file property (General tab of Properties) for .py has always been "Python File". After installing Python 3.8 (with Python Launcher) just to try, then uninstalling both Python 3.8 and Python Launcher, I noticed that the Property of all my Python scripts changed. Instead of saying "Python File" it now shows "PY File".
The association was also wiped out. When in cmd windows executing "assoc .py" I got nothing back.
Of course, double clicking on any .py script would not run the script, but just open in a window that looked like a debugger (it was not PyCharm).

Form cmd I run "assoc .py=Python File", which restored the lost association, and now double clicking works. But when I open the Property (after right-click on the file), in the General tab the Type of file still says "PY File" instead of "Python file".
I also tried to see if I can find anything in the registry, but found nothing that was related.
I should also add that the icon for the .py file has also changed in the process.
Any ideas on what could have happened and how to change it back (if possible without reinstalling Python) would be much appreciated. Also, what is "PY", the new file type for .py?

Comment: on windows "py" is an alias for "python" on the command line. So for many windows users "python.exe foo.py" and "py foo.py" do essentially the same thing as does "python foo.py"

Answer (score 0):

I tried py in cmd window and got "'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command". But when typing python I got the python interactive started.